# Global solution to use the correct screen height and width in Xamarin.Forms android?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a new app for a client with Xamarin.Forms for Android and iOS platforms, everything goes well since I decided review the app in different screen sizes in android platform.

Seems like Xamarin.Forms is ignoring the system navigation tray and every element in the each view appear under the system bar. I know this can be fixed with `OnPlatform` stament or `SizeChanged` event in the XAML.CS, but I want to know if exist a global approach to fix that issue instead making little fixes for each page.

Take a look to one of my pages.

Almost all pages in my app are done with `Grid`, so here I have 3 rows, the second one with 2 columns; in iOS pages works perfectly... but android... it's a really somehow painful.

Thanks in advance.

** ADDED CODE FROM MAINACTIVITY **

```
[Activity(Label = "MyBankingApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = 
"@style/MainTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
ConfigChanges.Orientation, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize,
          ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

I've these three methods:

```
    public void AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid () {

        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) this.FindViewById (Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        mChildOfContent = content.GetChildAt (0);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = mChildOfContent.ViewTreeObserver;
        vto.GlobalLayout += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            possiblyResizeChildOfContent ();
        };
        frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.LayoutParameters;
    }

    private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent () {
        int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight ();
        if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
            int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.RootView.Height;
            int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;

            frameLayoutParams.Height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;

            mChildOfContent.RequestLayout ();
            usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }

    private int computeUsableHeight () {
        Android.Graphics.Rect r = new Android.Graphics.Rect ();
        mChildOfContent.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame (r);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) {
            return (r.Bottom - r.Top);
        }

        maxHeight = Math.Max(maxHeight, r.Bottom);
        return r.Bottom.Equals(maxHeight) ? maxHeight : (int)(maxHeight* 0.8);
    }
```

Notice I'm mainly iOS developer, so Android is a little hard to me to understand sometimes.

my styles.xml

```
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#181F27</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#181F27</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#7FAD30</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#7FAD30</item>
  </style>
     <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashbg</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>  
  </style>
</resources>
```

[image: Android system navigation bar overlay in Xamarin.Forms]

Comment: What i assume is that your problem is the android theme that is assigned in your main activity so can you just show me the theme if possible

Comment: Hi @G.hakim, I added some methods from MainActivity class. Also, I hace this `[Activity(Label = "MyBankingApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize,
              ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]`

Comment: What i want you to do is go to your styles.xml under your resource/values folder and paste your maintheme here

Comment: @G.hakim sorry, I added the whole file in the description.

Comment: Check my ans out

Answer (score 0):

- In your Android project add the following theme:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" 
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
<item name="spinBars">true</item>
 <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">#003399</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#003399</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#003399</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#012348</item>
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

- Create a folder named values-v21 and add an XML named styles.xml and add the following code to it :

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <resources>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
   <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
   <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
   <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
   </style>
   </resources>
  ```

And use the name myTheme as the app theme in all your Android activities:

Something like this :

```
[Activity(Label = "MyBankingApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Revert in case it doesn't work

Comment: It changed nothing ? if so i want you to show me your solution and your new style folders and activity code